# winsock client socket is invalid

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, winsock

I want to *connect* to a specific server with this client-code using winsock.
But the *created socket* is *invalid*, so that I get **"INVALID SOCKET"**.

```
//Creating a socket for connecting to server
SOCKET hSocket;
hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (hSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)   //this is true!
{
    cout << "INVALID SOCKET" << endl;
}

/* This code assumes a socket has been created and its handle
is stored in a variable called hSocket */
sockaddr_in sockAddr;

sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(54123);
sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

// Connect to the server
if (connect(hSocket, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR while connecting" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I can think of is that you didn't `WSAStartup()` the winsock.
Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx if you didn't. You can also use `WSAGetLastError` to see what's wrong.

Add at the top of your code:

```
WSADATA wsaData;

//activate ws2_32.lib
int res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData);
if (res == 0){
    cout << "WSAStartup successful" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Error WSAStartup" << endl;
    return -201;
}
```